# Selenium cant find element by id, yet it exists

Tags: python, selenium, shopware

So basically my script goes to the product-creation page of my shop, then logs in, after redirect it should put in the product title.

For that i wanted to use selenium, as this shop system has no useful API features for me.

the code that does the trick is following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url3 = 'https://mywebsite.net/admin#/sw/product/create/base'
browser.get(url3)
swu = 'admin'
swp = 'password'
browser.find_element_by_id('sw-field--username').send_keys(swu)
browser.find_element_by_id(
    'sw-field--password').send_keys(swp)
browser.find_element_by_class_name('sw-button__content').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_id(
    'sw-field--product-name').send_keys('dsdsdsdssds')
```

However, my script perfectly recognizes the admin and password field by id, but after login and redirect it cant recognize the product title field.

The shop system is shopware 6

Comment: Still wondering why you are using selenium - Shopware 6 is "API-first" so everything you can do with the admin panel can also be done via API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you haven't provided any HTML to work with (or a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), I can't give an answer specific to your use case. However, the solution is likely to be that you need to use [Selenium's expected conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://mywebsite.net/admin#/sw/product/create/base")
...
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Another notable cause of the element not being visible to selenium is when it's contained within an `iframe`. If that's the case, you'll need to use `switch_to_frame` as described in the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html?#moving-between-windows-and-frames).

Comment: The source code: https://pastebin.com/tWTpsrF5 i noticed the id isnt even in the source code, however in element inspection i can see the id, looks like this: https://ibb.co/h9HVf4t

Comment: The content appears to be generated using Vue, which is why it's not in the src. A picture of the element doesn't help me help you, unfortunately. Try implementing my above answer and if that doesn't work, update your question but read how to make a reprex first. Include the errors.